# Migrating from ASP.NET 4 website project to web application project in Visual Studio 2010 Causing all controls to throw error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I recently updated my VS2010 website project from .NET 3.5 to 4.0.  Everything was working fine in the website project.  Today I decided to migrate the website to a web application project as I have learned this is the best way to work in .NET.  I split out all my class files into a separate class library and copied all my other content into my new project.  Then I updated all the references and web.config.

**When I build the class library, everything works great.**

The problem is happening when I try to build/debug the web application project.  It is acting like all the controls are missing and it is also throwing a bunch of compile errors about the public properties I have in my master pages.

Control errors:

> "The name 'INSERT CONTROL NAME HERE' does not exist in the current context"

Master page errors:

> 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition....

It is giving these errors for every single control and master page property in my entire solution.

I notice when I add a new web.form to this project, it also adds a filename.aspx.designer.cs file in addition to the .aspx and .aspx.cs file. My existing files do not have these extra files since they were created in a different .NET version.

Anyone have an idea on how to overcome these issues?

**UPDATE:**  It seems I was missing the step where I need to right click on the new application folder and select "Convert to web application".  I just did that and it seems to be a little bit better...

Now it is choking on Literals that are inside single quotes:

```
<div class='<asp:Literal ID="CssClassLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>'>
```

It doesn't see this literal when it does the conversion... Is the above valid code or should I implement that functionality another way?

Comment: Regarding your updated issue - I wouldn't do it that way. Either give that div an id and runat="server" and update the class that way, or use an asp:panel.

Comment: Thanks... I just converted it over to use a public property - eg <%# CssClass %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - one of the main differences between the website project and a web application project in Visual Studio is that the web application project defines a designer.cs file for every page/user control.

So, let's say you have a page in a website with a codebehind:

```
Default.aspx
Default.aspx.cs
```

In a web application, the designer is now required:

```
Default.aspx
Default.aspx.designer.cs
Default.aspx.cs
```

The designer file is auto-generated, but you may need to "touch" each page to generate.